# Unable to connect Windows Server 2012 R2 to a Domain Controller. Getting Error

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, netbios

I am unable to connect Windows Server 2012 R2 to a Domain Controller. Getting Error,

`An Attempt to Resolve the DNS name of a domain controller in the domain being joined has failed. Please verify the client is configured to reach a DNS server that can resolve DNS names in the target domain`

But the Client Server is able to ping the domain as well as it is able to resolve it. (checked it using nslookup), While adding the domain, it popup the authentication window after that it shows the above-provided error.

[image]

Comment: Yes I am able to resolve it. Also I am using FQDN as the domain name to connect with.

Comment: Have you checked that you can resolve the FQDN of every *domain controller*, not just the FQDN of the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following:

- ONLY internal DNS servers are configured on the client server; mixing
  internal/external DNS servers is 1. a bad idea, and 2. doesn't do
  what you think it does
- All appropriate Service Locator Records for the domain are present
  (found in _msdcs.domain.com)
- All A records for all domain controllers are present in the
  forward lookup zone domain.com
- A properly formatted reverse lookup zone for x.y.z.in-addr.arpa
  exists for the subnet(s) of your Domain Controller(s) (where your subnet is the form of z.y.x.0)